# focus at the end of the text in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a requirement: a text box can have a max of 50 characters, to achieve this I gave preventDefault.

```
if (!(event.ctrlKey && (event.which == 65 || event.which == 86 || event.which == 67 || event.which == 88))
                && (!(event.shiftKey && (event.which == 35 || event.which == 36)))
                && (key != 8 && key != 37 && key != 39 && key != 46 && key != 36 && key != 35 && key != 33 && key != 34)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
```

But now the requirement is : when we press ctrl+a and then abc it should erace everything from the text and print abc.
to achieve this i wrote this code ->

```
var focusItem = $('<input type="text">');
     function getSelText() {
              var txt = '';
              //IE
        var focusItem = $('<input type="text">');
         if (document.selection != undefined) {
             focusItem.focus();
             var sel = document.selection.createRange();
             var rangeParent = sel.parentElement();
             txt = sel.text;
             if (!(event.ctrlKey && (event.which == 65 || event.which == 86 || event.which == 67 || event.which == 88))
             && (!(event.shiftKey && (event.which == 35 || event.which == 36)))
             && (key != 8 && key != 37 && key != 39 && key != 46 && key != 36 && key != 35 && key != 33 && key != 34)) {
             //event.preventDefault();
            if (txt.length > 0 && ((key >= 65 && key <= 90) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 97 && key <= 122))) {
                sel.text = String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase();
                }
                txt = sel.text;
             }
          }                        
          return txt;
       }
```

now things are working but.. when I press ctrl+a abc then its getting printed as bca. Whats happening is : When i press a after ctrl+a then a is getting printed on the textbox but the focus is getting set before the text, that is a.
How to deal with this.
I am using windows 7, IE9, visual studio 2010.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to set the focus to the end of a textbox is to just set the text of the textbox to itself:

```
focusItem.val(focusItem.val());
```

Comment: I tried checking the value of focusItem  `if (txt.length > 0 && ((key >= 65 && key <= 90) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 97 && key <= 122))) { 
                sel.text = String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase(); 
                } 
                txt = sel.text; 
             } 
`  but it returns null.

Comment: If your textbox has an id of `myTextBox` then doing `$('#myTextBox').val( $('#myTextBox').val() )` will place the cursor at the end.  You just need to get the value of your textbox, don't need to try and create a selection range for that part.

Comment: If you can create a jsfiddle.net of your code and add the link to your question it would make answering your question a lot easier. Hard to tell where the problem is right now.